# unfortunately API demo has stopped while running

Tags: android

I have developed an app for page navigation . when a button is clicked the page should navigate to the second page. when i run the project and opened my app its showing unfortunately API demo has stopped. I have posted the entire code of my app . PLS HELP ME OUT...

//MAIN ACTIVITY

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Click" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Main Activity" />

</RelativeLayout>

//SECONDSCREEN ACTIVITY

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sceond Screen Activity" 
        tools:context=".SecondScreenActivity"/>

</LinearLayout>

//JAVA CODE FOR MAIN ACTIVITY

package com.example.navigate;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addButtonOnClickEventListener();

    }

    public void addButtonOnClickEventListener()
    {
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Context context = this;
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,SecondScreenActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
             }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}

// JAVA CODE FOR SECOND SCREEN ACTIVITY

package com.example.navigate;
import android.app.Activity;
public class SecondScreenActivity extends Activity {

}



 // MANIFEST FILE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.navigate"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.navigate.SecondScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

        </intent-filter>

       </activity>

     </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: where you are registering `MainActivity` in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: you are not define your mainactivity in your manifest and also not do any oncreate method in secondactivity..

Comment: could you pls tell me where to mention the mainactivity in manifest file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem MainActivity is your launcher page here but you define the secondactivity as luncher in manifest.change it first.

Add an oncreate() to secondactivity otherwise there is nothing to show when the button click.

Third change your MainActivity Context to activity which is MainActivity.this not local

Other things are fine , and hope you understand your small problems..

Change your manifest to something like this:

```
 // MANIFEST FILE
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.navigate.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

    </intent-filter>

   </activity>

   <activity android:name = ".SecondScreenActivity" />

 </application>
```

And in your SecondScreenActivity add an oncreate method with the contet view like:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity_layout);

}
```

And also in your mainactivity change the **context** to `MainActivity.this` . Here you define the context inside onclicklistener which links to your local method not the class.

Comment: thank you . so much sir .. its working... navigating to the second page.. but in between its showing unfortunatey API demo has stopped....but its still working